# Wordpress не видит изображения в css файле

Tags: php, css, wordpress, css3, cms

Все Привет, есть Wordpress и свой шаблон темы.

В css файле есть такая строка

```
background-image: url(../img/wash.png);
```

Но на сайте она не изображается и не подключается, в основном шаблоне подключаю изображения с помощью такого кода.

```
    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/img/image.png" rel="stylesheet" />
```

как понимаю в css тоже надо сделать что-то подобное или что ?
Подскажите пожалуйста добрые люди

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Исправь вопрос и удали мусор из него. Оставь только суть.

Answer (score 1):

Если структура папок такая, что пути выглядят так:

```
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/img/wash.png
```

то указывать относительный путь надо следующим образом:

```
background-image: url(img/wash.png);
```

Comment: Я вангую проблему в неправильном подключении css-файлов. Но хочется дождаться более внятных объяснений ТСа.;)

Comment: @SeVlad все может быть, информации мало.

Comment: css файлы подключены верно, иначе стили вообще не работали бы

Comment: не показываются только изображения

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(./img/wash.png);
```